# Easy way of extracting text in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose we have the following `fruit_type` constraint:

```
CHECK(((fruit_type)::text = ANY((ARRAY['apple'::character varying, 'pear'::character varying, 'orange'::character varying])::text[])))
```

How do we extract `'apple', 'pear'`, and `'orange'` from this string? Could we use the `substring` method?

Answer (score 0):

By referring to its index number:

```
select (ARRAY['apple'::character varying, 
'pear'::character varying, 'orange'::character varying]::text[])[1];
```